# User profile folders data Backup/transfer

Tags: windows-10, backup, user-accounts, user-profiles, data-transfer

looking a simple way to backup/transfer User profile data like Desktop, Documents, Downloads etc before doing any changes on system or installing a windows.
Any guides?

Comment: Simple enough - copy the folders.

Comment: is possible to copy all the folders one time together any cmd command help?

Comment: Not by one command. You need as many `copy` commands as folders.

Comment: If you're making major changes, make a *disk image*, not just specific folders. It may be the only way to recover from a mistake, and its' *fast* compared to copying all files, since most apps, such as Macrium Reflect, use direct disk I/O.